# How can I return a 404 error when the contextual filter value is provided in the URL, but the view returns no result?

Tags: views, 9

I'm on building a rest view of nodes using *Serializer* as formatter. This view has a contextual filter on a plain-text field of that content type.

How can I return a 404 error when the contextual filter value is provided in the URL, but the view returns no result?

I've tried various validators, such as *content*, *field*, or *basic validation*, but none of them does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'No Results Behavior' section for the view, click 'add', and choose 'Response Status Code', and set the value to 404.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not not working because under that section nothing can be added. It is actually stated  _"The selected display type does not use empty plugins"_